# Java sound - How to dynamically adjust sound pitch

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to make a simple game with an engine noise that goes up and down when player accelerates/decelerates.

From posts on SO I've got this little example...

```
public static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16 * 1024; // ~16KHz

public void playNoise() throws Exception {

    final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(Note.SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
    SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    line.open(af, SAMPLE_RATE);
    line.start();
    byte[] engineNote = makeEngineNote(); 
    line.write(engineNote, 0, engineNote.length);
    line.drain();
    line.close();
}

private byte[] makeEngineNote() {
    // Create a kind-of-sin-wave-with-interference
    byte[] b = new byte[SAMPLE_RATE];
    ...
}
```

Now I want to make the pitch fluctuate to mimic acceleration/deceleration. I was wondering about looping the above code (the `write()`) but I'm not sure how to change the wavelength on the fly. I can't imagine re-generating the wav each time is the most desirable approach. I could create multiple wav's with different wavelengths but this wouldn't give a smooth transition.

Any help/links would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The question isn't specifically about making an engine noise, the `makeEngineNote()` method is sufficient for my needs. The question is about adjusting the pitch without generating the wav each time.

Comment: An "engine sound" is extremely complex, a lot more than just a modulated sine wave.  You'd be better off finding a sound sample or capturing your own.  If you MUST generate it, you will have a long road of experimentation and adjustment ahead of you.

Comment: You could make a sci-fi engine sound with a saw wave, but I don't think this is the kind of thing we can reasonably explain how to write in a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison please see edit. I've also changed the title to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @Radiodef please see that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way, not sure how practical it is though.

I can copy the original wav, removing every `n`th byte. This gives the effect of the pitch increasing. `n` can then be derived from some variable which represents the engines throttle.

To make this less intensive I keep the wav as small as possible. Code basically looks a little like this...

```
    int n = ...; // Inverse of throttle; as n gets bigger sound gets lower.
    while (running) {
        byte[] b = removeEveryNthByte(engineNote, n);
        line.write(b, 0, b.length);
    }
```

Just need to see if caching will be of use.

Answer (score 0):

```
//change the frequency of Audio format from 44100 Hz to 72000 Hz.
private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {
    int ch = inFormat.getChannels();
    float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();  
    return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, 72000, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate,
            inFormat.isBigEndian());
}



//source file
final File file1 = new File(“Sample.mp3”);
//destination file
final File file2 = new File(“Sample_cat.wav”);
//audio stream of file1
final AudioInputStream in1 = getAudioInputStream(file1);
//get audio format for targetted sound
final AudioFormat inFormat = getOutFormat(in1.getFormat());
//get the target file audio stream using file format
final AudioInputStream in2 = getAudioInputStream(inFormat, in1);
//write the audio file in targeted pitch file
AudioSystem.write(in2, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file2);
```

From https://www.technetexperts.com/web/change-the-pitch-of-audio-using-java-sound-api/